# Android webview relative scrolling

Tags: android, webview

I need to be able to zoom to a relative position on the webview 
`webview.scrollTo(1500, 2000);` i need to use it like this `webview.scrollTo(0.75, 0.5);` which means move to 75% of x axis and 50% of y axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is scroll to the bottom of the webView (total pixels - webView height):

```
webView.scrollTo(0, (int) ((webView.getScale() * webView.getContentHeight())-webView.getHeight()));
```

You can multiplie this by needed percentage:

```
webView.scrollTo(0, (int) 0.5*((webView.getScale() * webView.getContentHeight())-webView.getHeight()));
```

Use same logic for x-axis.

Comment: There is no method called `webView.getContentWidth()`

Comment: now I see... for getting total width try to use following tutorial: http://android.pimmos.com/2011/03/24/how-to-retrieve-the-contentwidth-of-a-webview/